# Trying to apply regex to a column in a dataframe

Tags: regex, pandas

I have the following df:

```
               concatenar           buy_sell
1           BBVA2018-03-2020          sell
5           santander2018-03-2020      buy
```

I would like to apply regex to the `concatenar` column, where I would like to display the  `[A-Z][a-z]` inside that `column`  values.

This is what I have tried:

```
re.findall(r'[A-Z][a-z]*',df['concatenar'])
```

But outputs:

```
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

My desired output would be :

```
               concatenar     buy_sell
1                 BBVA         sell
5             santander         buy
```

How could I correctly apply the `regex` to the `concatenar` column?

Comment: Perhaps try using builtin replace method i.e `df['concatenar'].str.replace(r'[0-9]/-','')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`replace` with `dict`

```
df.concatenar.replace({r'\d+':'','-':''},regex=True)
Out[354]: 
1         BBVA
5    santander
Name: concatenar, dtype: object
```